# R(Studio) troubles installing SEMplot in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, r, rstudio

I want to install semPlot in R Studio under my Ubuntu 18.04 Sys.
I've tried the GUI Version of are Studio as well as the R Console with
install.packages("semPlot", dependencies = T)

The output indicates that dependencies are missing. I manually tried to install them. A google search revealed I might need to apt-get install some packages which I did, sadly it didnt fix the Problem. Here is to output of R

```
> install.packages("semPlot", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘rpf’, ‘XML’, ‘OpenMx’

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rpf_0.60.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 338272 bytes (330 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 330 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.19.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1600788 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/OpenMx_2.12.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3338898 bytes (3.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.2 MB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/semPlot_1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 71579 bytes (69 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 69 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘rpf’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rpf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rpf’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** Paket ‘XML’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
USE_XML2 = yes
SED_EXTENDED_ARG: -E
Minor 9, Patch 4 for 2.9.4
Located parser file -I/usr/include/libxml2/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  -I/usr/include/libxml2
Using libxml2.*
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... yes
checking for xmlHashSize in -lxml2... yes
Using built-in xmlHashSize
Checking DTD parsing (presence of externalSubset)...
checking for xmlHashSize in -lxml2... yes
Found xmlHashSize
checking for xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer in -lxml2... yes
have xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer()
checking for xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc in -lxml2... yes
checking libxml/xmlversion.h usability... yes
checking libxml/xmlversion.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h... yes
Expat:  FALSE
Checking for return type of xmlHashScan element routine.
No return value for xmlHashScan
xmlNs has a context field
Checking for cetype_t enumeration
No cetype_t enumeration defined in R headers.
checking for xmlsec1-config... no
nodegc default 
xml-debug default 
Version has XML_WITH_ZLIB
Version has xmlHasFeature()

****************************************
Configuration information:

Libxml settings

libxml include directory: -I/usr/include/libxml2
libxml library directory: -lxml2 -lz  -lxml2
libxml 2:                 -DLIBXML2=1

Compilation flags:         -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1 
Link flags:               -lxml2 -lz  -lxml2

****************************************
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/supports.R
config.status: creating inst/scripts/RSXML.csh
config.status: creating inst/scripts/RSXML.bsh
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c DocParse.c -o DocParse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c EventParse.c -o EventParse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ExpatParse.c -o ExpatParse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c HTMLParse.c -o HTMLParse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c NodeGC.c -o NodeGC.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RSDTD.c -o RSDTD.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RUtils.c -o RUtils.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rcatalog.c -o Rcatalog.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Utils.c -o Utils.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c XMLEventParse.c -o XMLEventParse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c XMLHashTree.c -o XMLHashTree.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c XMLTree.c -o XMLTree.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fixNS.c -o fixNS.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c libxmlFeatures.c -o libxmlFeatures.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c schema.c -o schema.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xmlsecurity.c -o xmlsecurity.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUSE_EXTERNAL_SUBSET=1 -DROOT_HAS_DTD_NODE=1 -DDUMP_WITH_ENCODING=1 -DUSE_XML_VERSION_H=1 -DXML_ELEMENT_ETYPE=1 -DXML_ATTRIBUTE_ATYPE=1 -DNO_XML_HASH_SCANNER_RETURN=1 -DLIBXML_NAMESPACE_HAS_CONTEXT=1 -DHAVE_XML_WITH_ZLIB=1 -DHAVE_XML_HAS_FEATURE=1 -DUSE_R=1 -D_R_=1  -DHAVE_VALIDITY=1 -DXML_REF_COUNT_NODES=1  -I. -DLIBXML2=1     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xpath.c -o xpath.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o XML.so DocParse.o EventParse.o ExpatParse.o HTMLParse.o NodeGC.o RSDTD.o RUtils.o Rcatalog.o Utils.o XMLEventParse.o XMLHashTree.o XMLTree.o fixNS.o libxmlFeatures.o schema.o xmlsecurity.o xpath.o -lxml2 -lz -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/XML/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘source’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘XML’
in method for ‘xmlAttrsToDataFrame’ with signature ‘"AsIs"’: no definition for class “AsIs”
in method for ‘readKeyValueDB’ with signature ‘"AsIs"’: no definition for class “AsIs”
in method for ‘readSolrDoc’ with signature ‘"AsIs"’: no definition for class “AsIs”
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (XML)
ERROR: dependency ‘rpf’ is not available for package ‘OpenMx’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/OpenMx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenMx’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘OpenMx’ is not available for package ‘semPlot’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/semPlot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘semPlot’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpNwbq6q/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("OpenMx", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘snow’, ‘rpf’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘Rmpi’, ‘snowfall’

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xml2_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 251614 bytes (245 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 245 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/snow_0.4-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 22675 bytes (22 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 22 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rpf_0.60.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 338272 bytes (330 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 330 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/roxygen2_6.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 178346 bytes (174 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 174 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rmpi_0.6-9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106745 bytes (104 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 104 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/snowfall_1.84-6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 344407 bytes (336 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 336 KB

versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/OpenMx_2.12.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3338898 bytes (3.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** Paket ‘xml2’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2
Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c connection.cpp -o connection.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_doc.cpp -o xml2_doc.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_init.cpp -o xml2_init.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_namespace.cpp -o xml2_namespace.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_node.cpp -o xml2_node.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_output.cpp -o xml2_output.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_schema.cpp -o xml2_schema.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_url.cpp -o xml2_url.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c xml2_xpath.cpp -o xml2_xpath.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o xml2.so RcppExports.o connection.o xml2_doc.o xml2_init.o xml2_namespace.o xml2_node.o xml2_output.o xml2_schema.o xml2_url.o xml2_xpath.o -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (xml2)
* installing *source* package ‘snow’ ...
** Paket ‘snow’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (snow)
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘rpf’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rpf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rpf’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘Rmpi’ ...
** Paket ‘Rmpi’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if pkg-config knows about OpenMPI... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking mpi.h usability... no
checking mpi.h presence... no
checking for mpi.h... no
configure: error: "Cannot find mpi.h header file"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpi’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rmpi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rmpi’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘roxygen2’ ...
** Paket ‘roxygen2’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c isComplete.cpp -o isComplete.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c leadingSpaces.cpp -o leadingSpaces.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c parser2.cpp -o parser2.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c wrapString.cpp -o wrapString.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o roxygen2.so RcppExports.o isComplete.o leadingSpaces.o parser2.o wrapString.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/roxygen2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (roxygen2)
* installing *source* package ‘snowfall’ ...
** Paket ‘snowfall’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (snowfall)
ERROR: dependency ‘rpf’ is not available for package ‘OpenMx’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/OpenMx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenMx’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpNwbq6q/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("rpf", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available
versuche URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rpf_0.60.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 338272 bytes (330 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 330 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘rpf’
* removing ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rpf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rpf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpNwbq6q/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("mvtorm", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘/home/durzo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mvtorm’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libopenmpi-dev using

sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev

and then try installing in Rstudio. It worked for me.